# Maps Android Studio no se muestra

Tags: android, google-maps

He estado aprendiendo como usar los Maps en android studio.
El proyecto me compila OK, pero cuando abro al app en el movil no se ve nada, solo la palabra google en la parte de abajo.

ya cree y agrege la api key. que puede estar pasando ?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDAEkJrbbqVfGLD7tWhksHRceh8Wqi-j8o" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"></activity>
</application>
```

[image: Key Creada y añadida al proyecto]

Comment: Alejandro, si no se ve nada es porque la AP_KEY es incorrecta, como la obtuviste? saludos.

Comment: Hola @Elenasys, la obtuve mediante [enlace](console.developers.google.com). seguí los pasos que allí indican.

Comment: Ve mi respuesta, asegurate de haber configurado el correcto paquete y SHA-1 para obtener el API KEY!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si tu mapa no es desplegado correctamente, es importante revisar dentro del `LogCat` , por ejemplo podrías tener este mensaje:

> Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.                                                                                             Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
>     API Key:
>     Android Application (;):
>   10:6D:D9:34:96:A6:1C:5A:45:5F:2C:C5:F7:FA:A5:E0:A2:D3:58:E0;com.pollitos.testapplication

**Para habilitar el [LogCat](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/help/am-logcat.html)**:
desde el menú: `Tools`-> `Android` -> [`Android Device Monitor`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/help/android-monitor.html) y ahí seleccionas el tab "[logCat](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/help/am-logcat.html)" donde se despliega información relacionada a tu aplicación.

#### La razón principal por la que no se despliega el mapa es porque no tiene el API KEY correcto o la api no esta habilitada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Repasando nuevamente los pasos para configurar correctamente Google Maps en una aplicación Android:

Vamos a  la consola de desarrollo para habilitar la `API de Google Maps`

https://console.developers.google.com

buscamos `Google Maps Android API` y vamos a la opción "`Credentials`"

Seleccionamos :
`Create Credentials` > `API KEY` > `Android Key`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agregamos una descripción y posteriormente agregamos el paquete de la aplicación y el certificado `SHA-1` que aparece en el `LogCat`, es importante agregues el paquete correcto ya que los permisos para visualizar el mapa se asignan dependindo del paquete y keystore utilizado (certificado `SHA-1`).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al Crear el API Key con estos valores obtendras un dialogo con el valor de tu API KEY a configurar en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al configurar este valor dentro de tu Manifest.xml

```
 <!--Google MAP API key-->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyAx7OiP9d4py5lWMOFfIrR63a9K-ikLTtw" />
</application>
```

Podrás cargar sin problema Google Maps en tu aplicación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

#### Es muy importante también comentar, que la `API KEY` depende del `Keystore` con el que se genera la aplicación. En mi caso tengo una API KEY generada a partir del `SHA-1` del `Kesytore` de debug y otra `API KEY` generada a partir del `Keystore` con el que se firma la aplicación en producción.

---

- Si estas trabajando en desarrollo obtén el SHA-1 del Keystore de desarrollo ubicado en :

`C:\Users\<user>\.android\debug.keystore`

registralo, obtén el API KEY y configurala en tu proyecto.

- En producción se debe obtener el SHA-1 del Keystore con el que se firma la aplicación para la Google Playstore, registrarlo, obtener la API KEY y configurar en el proyecto.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, he seguido esos paso y aun no logro visualizarlos mapas. <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDAEkJrbbqVfGLD7tWhksHRceh8Wqi-j8o"/> lo cree con estos datos, nombre de paquete: com.example.nano.prueba.login.loginprueba SHA-1: 93:07:78:D7:F4:83:3B:C2:6C:65:84:0F:07:DF:93:66:7E:85:2E:C8

Comment: Alejandro verifica en tu LogCat que mensaje se registra cuando intenta cargar el Mapa.

Comment: perdona la molestia estoy aprendiendo y no se como verificar los LogCat, me ayudas con esto tambien ? gracias.

Comment: No te preocupes, para habilitar el LogCat desde el menú: Tools-> Android -> Android Device Monitor y ahí seleccionas el tab "logCat" donde se despliega información relacionada a tu aplicación.

Comment: hola @Elenasys, gracias por tu ayuda, de momento no cambie nada y se arreglo, supongo que era alguna error en la key, seguramente no estaba actualizada en el sistema. muchas gracias.

Comment: mira que curioso, si ejecuto la app desde el modo depuración como el dispositivo como emulador, "funciona" puedo ver los maps, pero si la instalo desde el dispositivo, como un apk cualquiera app-release.apk ahi es donde NO se visualizan los matas, curioso, por que sucede esto??? @Elenasys

Comment: Agregaré más información a la respuesta, recuerda que el sha-1 se obtiene del Keystore con el que se firma la app, lo que puede ocurrir es que cuando cargas la aplicación en modo debug se usa un Keystore y cuando la firmas se usa otro. Yo tengo 2 api key configuradas, una para mi keystore de desarrollo y otra para firmar mi aplicación con el Keystore de producción!

Comment: Gracias gracias, si era ese el problema, que estaba sacando el sha1 del key equivocado, lo saque manualmente del key con el que estoy generando el apk y ahora si funciona.! mil gracias @Elenasys.... Utilice este comando para hacerlo keytool -list -v -keystore /home/david/Desktop/Keys/key.jks -alias MyAlias -storepass 456 -keypass 123

Comment: Excelente, agregue el comentario en la respuesta, saludos!

Comment: si encuentras oportuno meter en la respuesta, con keytool -list -v -keystore tukeystore.keystore se puede obtener el sh1 de la app firmada

Answer (score 2):

Preparativos para Android Studio

Siguiendo los pasos de la [Guia de Android Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start?hl=es) he podido extraer los requisitos previos para usar el servicio de Google Maps.

Instalar la `Google play Services` des de el `SDK Manager`
Crear apikey de `Google Places API for Android` en la consola: [console developer](https://console.developers.google.com)

Añadir la dependecias en archivo `app.graddle`

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

Crear **values/google_maps_api.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">
        <!-- código de la APIKEY
        https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get-key
        -->
    </string>
</resources>
```

aplicar el permiso `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` en el archivo `Manifest.xml` para poder usar google maps

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`

Y definir nueva activity

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

<activity
    android:name=".MapsActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"></activity>
```

Crear el layout **layout/activity_maps.xml**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.testsettings.app.testgooglemaps.MapsActivity" />
```

La activity donde quieres usar el elemento de google maps tiene que heredar de `FragmentActiity` y cargar la interfaz `OnMapReadyCallback`

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng myLocation = new LatLng(13.0810, 80.2740);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myLocation).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myLocation));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                new LatLng(myLocation.latitude, myLocation.longitude), 11.0f), 1500, null);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tengo el mismo problema, pero a mi no me carga cuando el dispositivo tiene habilitado únicamente el GPS, cuando el "Modo de ubicación" está en "modo de alta precision" con redes y Wifi, el mapa carga perfectamente.. sé que ese no fué tu problema pero lo dejo por si a alguien le está pasando lo mismo que a mi.

Comment: Esto no parece ser una respuesta a la pregunta, más bien es un comentario. Te sugiero que lo elimines, en cuanto tengas suficientes puntos de reputación podrás poner comentarios a las preguntas. Saludos!