# ¿ Cómo localizar en un mapa múltiples destinos?

Tags: java, android, webview, map

Estoy con un `WebView` dentro de un `Fragment` y estoy usando google maps para implementarlo , el problema es que yo necesito que al abrir google maps me marque varios destinos separados, y se vean a la vez en el mapa. Yo solo sé hacer eso pero con 1 destino, te vas a google maps, lo buscas, copias URL la copias al programa y te lleva , pero más de 1 destino no sé como se hace..

`public class Five_fragment extends Fragment {`

```
  WebView appWeb;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.five_tab, container, false);
   String url = "https://www.google.es/maps/search/direccion";
    appWeb = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.mywebview);
    //Habilitamos el javaScript y el zoom
    appWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    appWeb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    //Cargamos el enlace definido
    appWeb.loadUrl(url);
    //Este método es para que el navegador se quede en nuestra aplicación
    appWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

¿ Sabéis cómo hacerlo con `google maps` o sabéis que se puede hacer con `mapview` o con alguna herramienta?

Comment: Tu estas ocupando esta url https://www.google.es/maps/search/direccion, que solo te permite una direccion Busque en google "android webview url with multiple destinations" y encontré esta pagina https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31217903/android-google-maps-passing-multiple-destinations. Esta pagina muestra como se pueden colocar muchas direcciones en la url, y que se muestren todas esas direcciones en el mapa.
Lo que debes hacer es ocupar la siguiente url: https://www.google.com/maps/dir/fromAddress/toAddress1/toAddress2 Puedes ocupar el numero de direcciones que tu quieres, por ejemplo: -P

Comment: Las búsquedas que yo realicé y no encontré nada de lo que comentas, es decir, encontre cosas similares pero tal como lo dices no. Le echo vistazo más tarde y te comento, gracias jorge, **+1**

Comment: @RfMvs esto en realidad esta cargando multiples destinos en una página web, NO en un WebView o Google Maps.

Comment: eso me carga a mi en un webview lo que comento, pero sinceramente me lleva a multiples destinos... y no quiero que sea un navegador. ¿ No hay alguna forma de implementar un mapa mediante MapView o MapFragment y poner una serie de Markers sobre un mapa y que se vean? ¿ Realmente tengo que hacer tooooooodo lo del API de Google Maps para que salgan unos markers en el mapa ? Porque estoy siguiendo tutorial y no me aclaro..

Answer (score 1):

Definitivamente lo que deseas es dibujar dentro de un WebView varias rutas en una aplicación nativa Android, esto no lo consideraría correcto, **La principal razón es que en Android a diferencia por ejemplo de iOS el WebView tiene un navegador limitado**, no es es realidad un browser y puede no soportar varias Caracteristicas del Javascript.

implementa Google Maps en tu aplicación.

Este es un tutoríal

https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/6755/95

Lo que necesitas puedes realizarlo con la [**Google Maps Directions ÁPI**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/).

---

La opción sencilla para evitar abrir en un `WebView` lo que deseas es realizar un `Intent`, suponiendo deseo trazar una ruta :

- Mexico City
- Tepatitlan, Jal
- Guadalajara, Mexico

El intent para abrir el mapa sería:

```
String myRoute = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Mexico City,+MX/Tepatitlan, Jal./Guadalajara,+MX";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(myRoute));
startActivity(intent);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

otro ejemplo para trazar una ruta:

- Iasi, Romania.
- Brasov, Romania.
- Bucharest, Romania.

El `Intent` para abrir el mapa sería:

```
String myRoute = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/IASI,+RO/BRASOV,+RO/BUCHAREST,+RO";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(myRoute));
startActivity(intent);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pero yo no quiero que me muestre la ruta, lo que yo quiero es solo mostrar markers, esos puntos rojos tipicos de google, los que yo quiera sobre el mapa, sin tener que implementar todas las APIS. Me refiero, no puedo cargar el mapa de alguna forma y mediante codigo poner los markers? en tal longitud y latitud.....

Comment: Si solo quieres mostrar los markers, busca en google "google maps url with many markers" y revisa las modificaciones que se pueden hacer a la url para que te muestre los puntos como marcadores, incluso puedes modificar el zoom y otros parametros del mapa mediante la url.

Comment: Si  ademas de mostrar los markers, necesitas que al seleccioner markers se muestre información que tu quieras , modificar el color de los markers, cambiar el zoom, hacer polígonos, usar la camara etc, Si requieres algunas de esas características te recomiendo que revises este tutorial http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2016/05/google-maps-android-api-v2/

Answer (score 1):

@Elenasys tiene razón, te voy a explicar una lista de lo que necesitas agrandes rasgos:

-Marcadores (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker?hl=es-419): los marcadores representan un punto en el mapa, tienen latitud y longitud. Puedes crear los marcadores que quieras.

-Debes implementar diferentes métodos de google maps que puedes implementar en tus activitys o fragments, aquí algunas librerias que te pueden ayudar.

```
public class fragment extends Fragment
implements OnMapReadyCallback,
            GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
            GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
            LocationListener,
            GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener,
            GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener{
```

- Por ultimo debes mostrar todos los marcadores en el mapa, para esto puedes buscar soluciones como esta https://stackoverflow.com/a/14828739/3377472

Por ultimo, decirte que puedes buscar información para trabajar con la cámara de google maps, para modificar el zoom,etc.

Comment: De acuerdo, gracias a ambos, os doy +1, y lo miro más adelante, estuve mirando y sí que tenéis razón , echaré vistazo a las API. thanks!

Comment: De todas formas Jorge, al hacer webview con google maps, si que me carga y puedo hacer busquedas, me hace falta entonces usar las API y todo eso?

Comment: @Rf Mvs revisa la otra respuesta que encontré.