# Error para visualizar el Mapa en la aplicación

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Estoy trabajando con Api de google maps pero cuando la corro directamente en android studio funciona bien, pero al descargarla el mapa no se visualiza correctamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has hecho todo los pasos para integrar la API de google map en tu app?

Comment: Si así es integre todos los pasos de la API y la verdad no comprendo el por que me arroja eso.

Comment: Los permisos de internet los tienes?

Comment: @CésarManuelRíosGómez Habilitaste la API ?

Comment: Por favor, incluye las partes relevantes de tu código en la pregunta. De lo contrario, sólo un adivino podría contestarte

Comment: Si amigo muchas gracias aprecio tu punto de vista lo tendré muy en cuenta.

Answer (score 1):

Si no te muestra el mapa,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la razón principal por la que no se despliega el mapa es porque **no tiene el API KEY correcto o la api no esta habilitada**.:

```
   <application>
   ...
   ...
   <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
   ...
   ...
   </application>
```

Revisa esta pregunta que describe tu problema, además muestra como configurar Google Maps en una aplicación Android:

**[Maps Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6732/maps-android-studio/6755)**

Cuando configuras un correcto API KEY y Habilitas la API, no debes tener problema al mostrar el mapa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]