# Problemas al mostrar Google maps en produccion

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, google-api, keystore

No he logrado visualizar Google maps en modo producción, existen otras preguntas que se refieren a este caso, he seguido cada una de las indicaciones y consejos pero solo puedo visualizar google maps en el emulador pero no cuando se descarga o actualiza desde play store, para resolverlo estoy usando una app que he subido de prueba por lo que voy a compartir toda la información de claves sha-1, código, imágenes de las claves de APIs, si logro solucionarlo acá también lo lograré en la app original y es que me sucede lo mismo con tres proyectos que tengo.

En muchas preguntas con este mismo problema, la solución es que obtengan la huella digital de la keystore con la que se está subiendo la app a playstore y se configure en la clave para la API de google maps, he hecho esto pero sigo sin poder visualizar los mapas, a continuación todo el proceso que he realizado.

**activity_maps.xml**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="google.maps.tintal.MapsActivity" />
```

**MapsActivity.java**

```
private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    //Parroquie San Agustín
    LatLng unia01 = new LatLng(4.653980, -74.146397);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(unia01).title("Parroquia San Agustín").snippet("Diosesis de fontibon").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));

    //Uniagustiniana
    LatLng unia02 = new LatLng(4.653421, -74.145150);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(unia02).title("Uniagustiniana").snippet("Universitaria Agustiniana").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(unia01,17));
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDjd5MPotj1x8v96Hs05dIRTjdocektzWg" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" />
</application>
```

En AndroidManifest se encuentra referenciada la clave de API_KEY, la cual se encuentra habilitada con la Biblioteca Google Maps Android API de GoogleAPIs, donde se encuentra habilitada tanto para la keystore de prueba con el fin de poder visualizar los mapas en el emulador, donde se muestra sin problema; y también para el keystore de producción con el fin de visualizar los mapas en la app descargada o actualizada de playstore.

**Huella digital del keystore de producción.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además, habilité Firma de aplicacionde Google PlayStore.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se encuentra relacionada a la clave en GoogleAPIs:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La Biblioteca habilitada es Google Maps Android API

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Teniendo todo esto, aun no puedo ver los mapas en modo producción pero si en el emulador (**sha-1 de prueba**: A2:1C:33:62:F3:88:C2:62:C4:C5:C0:ED:BB:B9:D5:B7:53:4E:F7:3D), en LogCat para debug se muestra lo siguiente y el mapa se muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He instalado la aplicación NOX, donde descargo e instalo la app desde playstore y en Logcat me muestra lo siguiente y no se muestra el mapa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor, agradezco su ayuda, luego de terminar con el mapa sigo con notificaciones push en producción.

Comment: El problema aquí es que no se visualiza en el NOX player?

Comment: El problema es que no se visualizan los mapas en producción, cuando instalo la app desde playstore, alli muestro como agrego sha-1 de producción, y tengo habilitado dos uno para debug y el otro para producción pero solo puedo ver los mapas en el emulador, que podrá ser por favor.

Comment: ok solo una pregunta el SHA-1 que obtuviste del Keystore de producción lo agregaste?       @IvanAlfredo

Comment: Si... lo agregué, los dos que estan allí son el de producción y el otro es el de prueba...

Comment: revisa que la API KEY sea la correcta en tu aplicación.

Comment: Únicamente tengo habilitada Google Maps Android API ¿Cómo puedo revisar? o habilito todas las APIs que se refieran a mapas?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76520/discussion-between-elenasys-and-ivan-alfredo).

Comment: La respuesta ha este problema esta en este link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559602/android-studio-google-map-still-blank-on-real-android-device-on-release-apk

Comment: Tuve el mismo problema. Para solucionarlo debes contar con 2 keys, una para debug y otra para release. Aquí te dejo información sobre el detalle:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/50699/321188 Adicional a ello, agregar el SHA-1 que se genera en el panel de "firma de apps" de la PlayStore Console. Aquí te dejo la información sobre ello:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/183636/321188