# ¿Porque mi app no muestra mapa al descargarla de playstore?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, google-api

Tengo una App que muestra un mapa usando la Api de Maps, pero al descargarla de Playstore no se visualiza el mapa.
Esto es lo que tengo configurado:

Una Api key para debug, el SHA-1 lo obtengo del **google_maps_api.xml(debug)**

Una Api Key para producción, el SHA-1 lo obtengo del certificado con el que firmo la App para subirla y actualizarla.

El Api key de pruebas lo inserto en **google_maps_api.xml(debug)**.

El Api key de producción lo inserto en **google_maps_api.xml(release)**.

Al subir mi App firmada y con el api key de producción no me muestra el mapa, pero si cargo el apk **FIRMADO (el mismo que subo a playstore)** directamente a mi celular me abre el mapa normal, y en la consola puedo ver las peticiones que hago a esa Api key de producción sin problemas.

¿Alguna solucion o paso que se me este pasando?
Nota : La Api key la genero en una cuenta diferente a la cuenta con la que se sube la app, y el paquete de la app comienza con example.xxx no se si algo de esto afecte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta entrar a google play console
Ingresa a Administración de lanzamientos > Firma de apps 
Y selecciona los SHA1 de la huella digital del certificado y agrega estás a Google API Console
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Perfecto, lo que estaba buscando... 
En ningún lado dicen que tienes que agregar el SHA-1 que genera Google tambien. Gracias