# Google Maps Android se visualiza en gris (o blanco) en Release

Tags: android, google-maps

Tengo una app que usa los mapas de google, en debug todo funciona bien, pero al pasar a release, el mapa no se visualiza

el archivo `google_maps.api.xml` lo he creado fuera de debug, es decir lo tengo en `main/res/values/google_maps.api.xml`

en el `AndroidManifest.xml` lo asigno

```
<Aplication>
...

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
...
</aplication>
```

veo que dentro de `google_maps.api.xml` hay lo siguiente:

> Once you have your key (it starts with "AIza"), replace the
>   "google_maps_key"
>       string in this file.

Y si empieza por `AIza` donde consigo la clave para release?

Comment: Dale una mirada a este post: [Get API Key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup)

Comment: joder hoy no es mi dia, ahora me funciona en release pero no en debug porque me lo he cargado U_U par haber si no era cosa de mal merge

Comment: @Webserveis Hehe! :D Cuando registras las credenciales, agrega el mismo package name y los 2 SHA-1.

Comment: @Webserveis por cierto agregaré una Wiki para mostrar las formas de obtener el SHA-1 de losKeystore.

Comment: De paso tambien especifica que al agregar un nuevo sha1 se vuelve a generar otra clave y se debe restablecer la clave anterior y dar guardar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Tengo una app que usa los mapas de google, en debug todo funciona
>   bien, pero al pasar a release, el mapa no se visualiza

Recuerda que cuando obtenemos el API KEY es relacionada a el SHA-1 de nuestro Keystore, en desarrollo se usa el debug.keystore pero **para producción debes obtener el SHA-1 del Keystore con el que firmas tu aplicación y registrarlo**.

Incluso, puedes configurar los SHA-1 de desarrollo y producción para que funcionen correctamente cuando realizas pruebas en desarrollo y cuando firmas con tu keystore para la Google PlayStore.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Es importante comentar que al agregar un nuevo SHA-1, se genera una 
nueva API Key diferente.**

---

Si no te muestra el mapa,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la razón principal por la que no se despliega el mapa es porque **no tiene el API KEY correcto o la api no esta habilitada**.:

```
   <application>
   ...
   ...
   <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
   ...
   ...
   </application>
```

Revisa esta pregunta que describe tu problema, además muestra como configurar Google Maps en una aplicación Android:

**[Maps Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6732/maps-android-studio/6755)**

Cuando configuras un correcto API KEY y Habilitas la API, no debes tener problema al mostrar el mapa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, tengo el mismo problema, no me muestra mi mapa y me lo muestra en blanco, ya generé la clave SHA1 con mi api key pero ahora mi aplicación no se ejecuta, como que se abre pero se cierra y no entra ni al OnCreate.

Comment: @EriK Hola Erik si se cierra el problema debe ser otro, tienes alguna pregunta realizada para poderte apoyar! Es importante revises en el LogCat que mensaje  de error se muestra.

Comment: Sii gracias, tengo la pregunta en este enlace: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/122459/visualizar-google-maps-en-xamarin-android?noredirect=1#comment228373_122459 
es más, ya me habías comentado jajaja tenía problemas con la SHA1 pero ya la generé y ahora se cierra

Answer (score 2):

Complementando solución:

Se debe permitir el acceso de la app firmada, mediante el SHA1 de la aplicación firmada.

Para obtener el `SHA1` se debe usar el comando

`keytool -list -v -keystore tu_keystore.keystore`

y en el panel de api de google maps agregar el nombre del paquete con el SHA1, dar guardar.

> Ojo con hacer guardar se genera otro google_key_map, se debe restablecer la clave anterior y volver a dar a guardar, así se podrá ir añadiendo aplicaciones que comparte la key de mapas.

Comment: Otra forma de obtener el SHA-1, y mas fácil, es agregando a tu App una Map Activity (File, New, Google, Google Maps Activity). Automaticamente se crea en res/values el xml google_maps_api y allí te muestra el SHA-1 así como la liga para crear la Google Maps API key, y en ese mismo xml colocas la key.

Comment: A mi me muestra el mismo SHA-1 que el debug, puede que dependiendo del flavor que tengas selecionado al importar actividad mapa.

Answer (score 1):

A mi me ha funcionado añadiendo un SHA-1 más (aparte de la generada con el certificado). 
Es decir tengo 2 huellas digitales de certificado SHA-1 con el mismo nombre de paquete.

Se debe poner la SHA-1 que sale en la firma de aplicaciones de la consola de Play Store.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que os sirva, a mi me funciono.
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Al generar una Activity tipo Maps, se generan DOS archivos google_maps_api.xml, almacenados en DOS carpetas diferentes: una para debug y otra para release. Yo agregaba la nueva google_key_map generada con el SHA-1 obtenido segun las instrucciones proporcionadas por ejemplo en la respuesta aceptada aqui. Pero la incluía en el archivo google_maps_api.xml del directorio app/debug/res/values
cuando lo importante era incluirla en el del directiorio app/release/res/values.
Aprovecho para dar las gracias todas las veces que me ha sido de ayuda stackoverflow.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: acabo de encontrar una respuesta que explica mucho mejor que yo esto. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32544885/7875352