# Google Maps no se muestra en release

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play

Sigo con mi proyecto embarrancado en el intento de mostrar los **mapas de google maps** en **release** desde google play.

He leído y aplicado las diferentes respuestas a preguntas similares por otros compañeros y no me han funcionado.

En el intento de localizar el error, he creado una nueva app de prueba, con un solo mapa, el problema persiste, cuando genero la apk de release si la cargo directamente a mi dispositivo funciona correctamente, si la descargo de google play el mapa no se muestra.

Pasos que hago:

1. Build/SelectBuildVariant: cambio de debug a release.
2. busco Sha-1 con keytool de mi key de publicación via cmd(uso una que ya había generado en otro intento).
3. en console.developers.google.com/apis/library habilito la api de google Maps Android API.
4. utilizo un proyecto generado con anterioridad, genero una apikey nueva, la restringo a aplicaciones móbil,con Sha-1 obtenida y nombre package de mi app.
5. copio apikey y la pego en release/Google_maps_api.xml
6. Build/Generate Signed APK.Obtengo APK.
7. Cuelgo APK a GooglePlay....

.... y nada :(

¿Alguien tiene alguna sugerencia?

Comment: El problema es que al parecer tienes problemas con la clave Sha1, hay dos tipos de claves en cuando generas tu apk y cuando esta en google play ...

Comment: Por loque dices tiene pinta de que no tienes bien la API-key de google maps, prueba a generarla nuevamente en https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key?hl=ES. No utilices la clave generada para otra aplicación

Comment: Esto me parece un duplicado : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/103765/google-maps-android-se-visualiza-en-blanco-en-release/103777#103777

Answer (score 0):

> ¿Por qué sucede esto? esto ocurrió porque hay diferentes SHA1 en
> depuración y tipo de publicación.

La solución es agregando el *SHA1* de mi keystore usado (que usaste para construir la versión apk) a la consola de San Google

**Los pasos a continuación :**

*1- Obtenga la ruta de su almacén de claves*

cuando generas APK firmado

**Construir ----> Generar APK firmado ...**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no te olvides de hacer **Build Type --- release**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*2- Extraiga SHA1 para keystore usado, abra su comando de uso de terminal a continuación*

keytool -list -v -keystore "/Users/NT/Desktop/generalkey.jks"
se le pedirá una contraseña para su almacén de claves

cambiar la ruta a la ruta del almacén de claves  `keytool -list -v -keystore "keystore path"`

de huellas dactilares de Certificado: encontrará SHA1

*3- genera la clave de Android usando este SHA1 y tu nombre de paquete*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te sirva. !

Comment: Gracias Ash, pero los pasos que me indicas ya los realizé, sin éxito.