# Cómo obtener SHA-1 para producción para usar en firebase

Tags: android, android-studio, push-notification, sha1

Por favor me pueden ayudar con este tema, el caso es que en estoy agregando notificaciones push con `firebase` a mi proyecto android, tengo entendido que la huella digital `SHA-1`, si se va a subir la aplicación a `google play store`, se debe agregar el certificado de producción, lo que yo he hecho es obtener el `SHA-1` de prueba como por ejemplo se muestra en la imagen de ilustración,

> ¿Cómo obtengo el certificado de producción?

muchas gracias por su ayuda.

[image: Sha-1, certificado de pruebas]

Comment: Ivan , tiene una keystore con la cual firmas tus aplicaciones a producción?

Comment: Tengo el certificado que genero cuando firmo la app en android studio desde Build -> Generate signed apk, es un archivo con extención .jks

Comment: No sabía que se firmaban a producción o a prueba, solo hasta ayer que en un totorial de notificaciones push, mencionan el certificadodo de pruebas para el emulador y el de producción para subir a play store, por ese motivo creo que tampoco puedo visualizar los mapas.

Comment: en realidad el SHA-1 se obtiene para habilitar la API, si subes tu aplicación en desarrollo a tu dispositivo se firma con el keystore de desarrollo por ejemplo el SHA1 que muestras en la imagen. para producción debes obtener el SHA-1 con la Keystore que deseas  firmar tu aplicación a producción. @IvanAlfredo

Comment: , es similar a los Google maps https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/103765/google-maps-android-se-visualiza-en-blanco-en-release/103777#103777  funcionan pero cuando firmas la aplicación con el Keystore de producción no se visualizan, la razón es que este Keystore de producción usa otro SHA-1, revisa mi respuesta y comenta resultados. @IvanAlfredo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recuerda que para desarrollo se usa regularmente por default el keystore : `debug.keystore`, el cual esta localizado en la ruta:

```
%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

o especificamente la ruta en windows:

```
C:\Users\<username>\.android\debug.keystore
```

ruta en MacOS

```
/Users/<username>/.android/debug.keystore.
```

Este es el keystore que usamos para desarrollo, pero cuando subes una aplicación a Google PlayStore es necesario firmarla con un [keystore de producción el cual debes crear y no debes perderlo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8508/recuperar-llave-publicaci%C3%B3n-aplicaci%C3%B3n-android/8509#8509), este Keystore es con el cual se obtendría el SHA-1 para desarrollo.

> ¿Cómo obtengo el certificado de producción?

Actualmente estas utilizando el keystore de desarrollo:

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
-alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

**para obtener el SHA1 de producción debes usar usa el Keystore que generaste para producción**, por ejemplo suponiendo se encuentra en c:\android\keystore\Ivan.Keystore lo obtendrías de esta forma, especificando el respectivo alias y passwords:

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v -keystore c:\android\keystore\Ivan.Keystore
    -alias aliasProduccion -storepass storepassProduccion -keypass keypassProduccion
```

esto te mostrará un SHA-1 diferente al obtenido mediante el keystore de desarrollo.

---

**Obtener el SHA-1 del Keystore de debug desde Android Studio**

Otra forma de obtener el SHA-1 del Keystore de debug desde Android Studio se realiza desde la opción gradle, en la esquina superior derecha:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Selecciona el proyecto, ve a `Tasks` > `android` > `signingReport` al dar clic se mostrara en la consola el `SHA-1`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

**Obtener SHA1 en Android Studio usando la terminal.**

Otra opción para obtener el SHA1 del certificado de desarrollo es mediante la Terminal, escribimos:

```
gradlew signingReport
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si está escribiendo aplicaciones de Android en Xamarin, use esto: `keytool -list -v -keystore "% USERPROFILE% \ AppData \ Local \ Xamarin \ Mono para Android / debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

Comment: @Jorgesys estoy recibiendo errores en la consola, estoy con win 10, tengo el keystore en esta ruta: "C:\android\keystore\uniagustapp_certificado.jks" que es el que obtuve al firmar la app.

Comment: en la consola de comandos ejecuto: keytool -exportcert -list -v -keystore c:\android\keystore\uniagustapp_certificado.jks
    -alias aliasProduccion -storepass storepassProduccion -keypass keypassProduccion, me esta mostrando el mensaje: 'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Ese mensaje se debe a que keytool no se encuentra en donde lo estas ejecutando, de acuerdo a tu información me parece que debes ir a este directorio: C:\Archivos de programa\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin  y ahí desde linea de comandos debe llamar keytool sin problema. Recuerda también que storepassProduccion y keypassProduccion deben ser reemplazados por tus archivos. @IvanAlfredo

Comment: Enter keystore password:
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Comment: Ya pasé a otro momento creo que ya esto es otro caso porque ya me permite avanzar, muchas gracias.

Comment: @IvanAlfredo excelente Ivan, puedes ahora realizar otra pregunta y la comunidad con gusto te ayudará, saludos! Con respecto a "Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect java.io.IOException" , recuerda que el password del keystore puede no ser el mismo que el del alias, debes cuidar esa información,

Answer (score 3):

> Traducción de la [respuesta original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42799732/8933039) por [Steve C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1055954/steve-c)

Acabo de hacer esto para Branch.io y Firebase. Esto es exactamente lo que me dio mi MD5, SHA1 y SHA256:

Si está en Windows, vaya a la carpeta donde está su almacén de claves. Mantenga presionada la tecla shift y luego haga clic derecho. Debería ver "Abrir indicador de comando aquí" en la lista de opciones.

Cuando se abra el símbolo del sistema, escriba lo siguiente y obtendrá todo lo que necesita:

> keytool -list -v -keystore {yourkeystore}

Luego pedirá la contraseña. Ingrese su contraseña y presione enter. Entonces tendrás toda tu información necesaria.

**NOTA LATERAL**

Si desea guardar la información para usarla en el futuro, haga clic con el botón derecho y elija seleccionar todo. Presiona enter y luego pega tu editor de texto favorito. Guárdalo en tu keystore para que siempre tengas la referencia en caso de que lo necesites para otras sdk's / api's. Espero que ayude.

**Si es en Windows**

Mantenga presionada la tecla de inicio de Windows y presione "X". Seleccione "Sistema" Luego seleccione "Configuración avanzada del sistema" en el lado izquierdo. En la ventana emergente, haga clic en variables de entorno. En la sección Variables del sistema, busque "JAVA HOME" si no está allí, haga clic en nuevo. Escriba JAVA_HOME para el nombre de la variable. Ingrese lo siguiente para el valor de la variable:

> C: \ Archivos de programa \ Java \ jdk1.8.0_66

Asegúrese de que coincida con la versión JDK que tiene

Luego busque la variable "Ruta" y agregue:

> C: \ Archivos de programa \ Java \ jre7 \ bin

Asegúrese de que coincidan con las ubicaciones de sus entornos Java SDK y Runtime. Luego podrá acceder a keytool desde cualquier lugar a través del símbolo del sistema.

Comment: Creo que con esto llego al SHA-1 de prueba que ya he obtenido y no al de producción.

Comment: @IvanAlfredo Según tengo entendido, ciertos servicios de Google Play (por ejemplo, el inicio de sesión en Google) requieren que se proporcione la huella digital SHA1 del certificado utilizado para firmar la aplicación. Al desarrollar una aplicación con Android Studio, el IDE crea un certificado de depuración autofirmado que se utiliza para firmar la aplicación en desarrollo. Debe registrar la huella digital de este certificado con la consola de Firebase para acceder a los servicios de Google Play.  [más información aquí](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html)

Comment: @IvanAlfredo [Aquí](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth) también hay más información al respecto.

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a consultar la info antes de aplicar la respuesta.

Comment: @IvanAlfredo no hay problema no se trata de yo obtener puntos, al final lo importante es que puedas solucionar el problema, Saludos!

Comment: ya he configurado JAVA_HOME, pero la variable Ruta no la he configurado, no existe, debo crearla ¿que hace?

Comment: @IvanAlfredo como configurar las [Variables de entorno para la instalación de Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26640589/8933039)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75585/discussion-between-ivan-alfredo-and-j-rodriguez).