# No se instala apk generada por android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

Acabo de terminar una aplicación desarrollada en android studio, siempre la instalé en mi dispositivo por medio de usb device para testearla un poco. Quise generar la apk para probarla en otros dispositivos y después de instalada la aplicación se detiene al iniciar. Esto pasa tanto generando por debug como release y marcando ambas casillas V1 y V2 como sugieren en algunos foros. Los permisos de aplicación están dados.

Como nota adicional indico que cuando terminé el login de la aplicación que conecta a firebase, generé una apk como release y efectivamente funcionó.

Aquí el gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'


android {
compileSdkVersion 28
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {

    applicationId "com.example.daniel.fitgo"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-beta01'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'


implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'




implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.0.0'





implementation project(':mylibrary')

implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

[image: Manifest]

De antemano, muchas gracias

Comment: Hola, consulta los otros dispositivos que probaste instalar que versión de android tienen? Si son inferiores te recomiendo utilizar el Multidex en la clase Application. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex?hl=es-419

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que estas haciendo uso de una API,

```
   <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
```

cuando [restringes el uso de la API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/signup#restrict-key) defines el package name y el SHA-1 del Keystore con el cual firmas la aplicación.

En este caso cuando la subes directamente a tu dispositivo el .apk es firmado con el [`keystore` (certificado debug) de desarrollo, pero cuando la firmas  con otro `keystore` diferente para producción (certificado release)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/signup#getting-the-certificate-information-yourself), por lo tanto los SHA-1 son diferentes

Obten el SHA-1 del `Keystore` con el cual firmas tu aplicación y configuralo en tu API.

[Cómo obtener SHA-1 para producción para usar en firebase](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/153203/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-sha-1-para-producci%C3%B3n-para-usar-en-firebase/153220#153220)