# statuscode=error resolution=null Google place api

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places

Añadí [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro) a mi app, pero cuando presiono me muestra el mensaje:

> statuscode=error resolution=null

No se muestra tampoco el mapa.

Esto me llega a pasar solo cuando genero la apk firmada para subir a la google play, cuando genero la apk sin firmar o le corro directamente en un emulador, este error no es generado...

Espero recibir ayuda ante este problema...

Comment: ¿imagino no se muestra el mapa tampoco?

Comment: @Elenasys estas en lo correcto, tampoco se muestra el mapa...

Comment: Obten el SHA-1 de tu keystore con el cual firmas tu aplicación para Google Play y configuralo en la API, revisa mi respuesta @WilsonCajisaca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre solucionar este problema.
[image: Imagen referencia]

1. cambiar en la esquina de modo android a modo project
2. Dirigirse a la carpeta src
3. buscar la carpeta release y dentro de esta el archivo

> google_maps_api.xml

Con eso para mi empezo a trabajar

Comment: ¿Entonces no tenias definida la API Key en realidad? , no entiendo como pudo haber funcionado la api en desarrollo

Comment: Lo que pasa es que lo tenia definido la key en el archivo `google_maps_api.xml` de la carpeta debug mas no en el archivo de la carpeta _release_ como se logra apreciar en la imagen

Comment: En este caso como se usa la misma API Key te sugiero usar solo un archivo res/values/google_maps_api.xml

Comment: Exactamente eso es lo que estoy haciendo ahora...

Answer (score 2):

Cuando defines la API key de Google Places dentro de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`, esta API se configura para el paquete de tu aplicación y para el certificado SHA-1 de tu keystore, ejemplo:

package name:

```
com.example.android.places-example
```

SHA-1:

```
BB:0D:AC:74:D3:21:E1:43:67:71:9B:62:91:AF:A1:66:6E:44:5D:75
```

Si tu aplicación no muestra problemas en este caso:

> cuando genero la apk sin firmar o le corro directamente en un emulador

se debe a que solo tienes registrado en tu API el certificado SHA-1 de desarrollo y no del keystore con el cual firmas la aplicación.

**Obtén el certificado SHA-1 del keystore con el cual firmas tu aplicación para subir a Google Play y agregalo.**

Revisa esta información relacionada :

[Cómo obtener SHA-1 para producción para usar en firebase](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/153203/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-sha-1-para-producci%C3%B3n-para-usar-en-firebase/153220#153220)

[Google Maps Android se visualiza en blanco en Release](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/103765/google-maps-android-se-visualiza-en-blanco-en-release/103777#103777)

[Restringir API Key](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/signup#restrict-key)

---

Generalmente debes tener esta configuración en tu API para que el uso de la API funcione tanto al subir la aplicación a tu dispositivo como al firmar para Google Play Store:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Amigo ejecuto este comado pero me genera el mismo sha1 que ya lo tenia definido... 'keytool -exportcert -list -v -keystore C:\Users\PCX\.android\debug.keystore' supongo que es por lo de 'debug.keystore' pero no tengo ningun otro archivo con la extencion keystore...

Comment: No, ese precisamente es el firma pa app cuando la subes a tu dispositivo, con cual firmas tu app a playstore, ese es el que debes usar.

Comment: Ya logre generar el nuevo sha1, resulta que e estado llamando mal al directorio donde estaba almacenado el jks... Pero sigue sin funcionar tanto el mapa con el google place... Debo añadir algo en el proyecto en Android studio tambien tal vez?

Comment: Debes definir el SHA-1 y el paquete de la aplicación en la consola para que funcione la API en tu aplicación. Es la misma aplicación?

Comment: Amigo no se que pasa, incluso en la console de google en el apartado de restrigciones de la api, le pongo ninguna pero ni aun asi funciona cuando la app esta en modo release...

Comment: Revisa que el API Key no haya cambiado @WilsonCajisaca , debes tener dos registros de restricción uno para desarrollo y otro para la app firmada para Google Play revisa la imagen que anexo.

Comment: Logre solucionarlo, el problema era dentro del proyecto android studio...