# Esta IP, sitio o aplicación móvil no está autorizada para usar esta clave API

Tags: android-studio, api, google-maps, geolocalización

Compañeros que tal, estoy teniendo dificultades con la **Api de google maps**, me sale el siguiente error **(IMAGEN)**, estoy trazando una ruta entre 2 marker, he revisado otras respuestas de otros compañeros de este mismo sitio, preguntas similares, he encontrado algunas respuestas, una de ellas  mencionan que en vez de la API key ponga una clave servidor, sinceramente no logro entender como obtener esa clave. Por favor los compañeros que hayan tenido este problema compartan su experiencia y ayundeme a resolver este problema. 
Se los Agredezco de todo corazon.

[image: Imagen]

**Este es mi metodo**

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;
map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {

                if (actualPosition){
                    latitudOrigen = location.getLatitude();
                    longitudOrigen = location.getLongitude();
                    actualPosition=false;

                    LatLng miPosicion = new LatLng(latitudOrigen,longitudOrigen);

                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(miPosicion).title("Aqui estoy yo"));

                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(new LatLng(latitudOrigen,longitudOrigen))
                            .zoom(15)
                            .build();
                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));


                    String KEY = getString(R.string.google_maps_key);
                    final String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + "" + latitudOrigen + "," + longitudOrigen +
                                 "&destination=-2.1172431,-79.892731&key="+KEY+"";

                    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
                    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {

                            try {
                                jso = new JSONObject(response);
                                trazarRuta(jso);
                                Log.i("*RUTA GENERADA*: ",""+response);
                                Log.i("*WEB SERVICES*" , url);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        }
                    });

                    queue.add(stringRequest);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

**Este es el metodo trazarRuta**

```
private void trazarRuta(JSONObject jso) {

        JSONArray jRoutes;
        JSONArray jLegs;
        JSONArray jSteps;

        try {
            jRoutes = jso.getJSONArray("routes");
            for (int i=0; i<jRoutes.length();i++){

                jLegs = ((JSONObject)(jRoutes.get(i))).getJSONArray("legs");

                for (int j=0; j<jLegs.length();j++){

                    jSteps = ((JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");

                    for (int k = 0; k<jSteps.length();k++){


                        String polyline = ""+((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                        Log.i("end",""+polyline);
                        List<LatLng> list = PolyUtil.decode(polyline);
                        map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().addAll(list).color(Color.RED).width(5));

                    }

                }

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: ¿Cómo tienes configurado los límites de uso de la api?

Comment: ¿Podrías decirme si la clave es tuya? Me sería de ayuda para ver cómo responderte.

Comment: Es la clave de Api que genere desde la consola de desarrollador, es la misma que use en el web services de googleMaps

Comment: Tengo activadas estas API'S      Directions API
    Geocoding API
    Geolocation API
    Maps SDK for Android
    Places API

Answer (score 0):

El problema es justamente que la IP, sitio o aplicación, que estás usando para conectarte a la API no está permitida para hacer uso de la key API que usas.

Es posible que hayas configurado restricciones para ella y te hayas olvidado.

Para cambiarlas lo que debes hacer es:

- Ir a https://code.google.com/apis/console, e iniciar sesión con la cuenta de Google que posee el proyecto con dicha key API.
- Abre tu proyecto.
- Ve al apartado **API y servicios**.
- Ve a **Credenciales**.
- Busca tu key API y editala desde el ícono de Lápiz.
- Baja a la parte de restricciones y selecciona **Ninguna** para deshabilitarlas o en su defecto, configura la que deseas.

También tienes la opción de que tu key API solo funcione con determinadas APIs, configúralo a gusto.

Para aplicaciones de Android, comúnmente se restringe mediante su nombre de tu paquete y huella digital de certificado de firma SHA-1.

Una vez selecciones **Apps de Android** como restricción se te mostrará un tutorial a la derecha. Aquí en Stackoverflow en español también hay una pregunta, cuya solución enseña a obtenerla: [Cómo obtener SHA-1 para producción para usar en firebase](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/153203/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-sha-1-para-producci%C3%B3n-para-usar-en-firebase)

Comment: Estimado segui sus pasos, modifique las retriciones del API, le puse NInguna y no restringir clave, al parecer ahora me arrojo esto: 
"You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at, me manda a un link que dice algo de facturacion.

Comment: Eso quiere decir que debes proporcionar un método de pago porque alguna de las API seleccionadas es de pago. Accede a https://console.cloud.google.com/billing si deseas añadir una cuenta de facturación.

Comment: Ahora entiendo, pense que las Api que seleccione eran gratuitas, le agradezco por su ayuda

Comment: No, cuando agregas una API que es de pago te dice los precios de ésta.