# Firmar un APK con un certificado dado

Tags: android, firma-digital

Tengo una aplicación en Android ya hecha, solo necesito compilarla para obtener el release y asi el APK.
Para obtener el APK necesito firmarlo primero, pero tengo que hacerlo con 2 archivos que me enviaron:
`bancavirtual.crt` y `bancavirtual.ca-bundle`

Primer necesito el fingerprint SHA256 de este certificado y luego como podría yo firmar con ese certificado, osea sacar del .crt el .jks para poder firmar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener el certificado SHA256 lo puedes realizar de la misma forma que se obtiene el certificado SHA1:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisa esta respuesta:

[**¿Cómo obtener clave SHA1 y SHA256  de certificado instalado en dispositivo Android?**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/153203/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-sha-1-para-producci%C3%B3n-para-usar-en-firebase/153220#153220)

Para firmar tu aplicación debes usar un archivo `.jks` o un archivo `.keystore`, ambos son archivos binarios que funcionan como almacén de claves, si en tu caso tienes `.jks`

Va el menú, selecciona `Build` > `Generate Signed Bundle / APK`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Seleccionas el "Android App Bundle" o "APK" que deseas generar firmado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Seleccionas el archivo `.jks`, escribes el Key Store password que definiste, su alias y el Key password

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

posteriormente solo indicas el tu .apk a firmar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]