# No se muestran los Maps en mi proyecto Android

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, android-layout

Al ejecutar el emulador en Android Studio puedo ver los maps, pero si la instalo desde el dispositivo, como un apk cualquiera como "app-release.apk" ahi es donde NO se visualizan los mapas Por favor necesito ayuda. Muchas gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿y el código que has utilizado? Edita tu pregunta y agrega. Saludos y bienvenido a SOes :D

Comment: Israel, te recomiendo agregar código, layouts o manifests como texto en tu pregunta, además agrega detalles, revisar [ask]. Cual es la referencia con el .apk que instalas en tu dispositivo? , el keystroke para format? Si esto es así la respuesta es obtener el sha-1 de este keystore y registrarlo, revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/103765/google-maps-android-se-visualiza-en-blanco-en-release @IsraelNinaVargas