# Al generar .apk relase no muestra los mapas en google maps

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api

Tengo una aplicación que hace uso de google maps al momento de correrla todo bien me muestra los mapas pero cuando creo el app release ya no muestra los mapas saque el certificado SH-1 que me dan al introducir el siguiente comando

```
keytool -list -v -keystore your_keystore_name -alias your_alias_name
```

y como SH-1 de publicacion me da = 24:90:B4:1C:7F:FE:4D:7C:BA:D1:3D:2A:15:50:55:55:14:69:B9:12

y el de depuracion es el siguiente=
D0:B7:C8:18:8F:1E:D4:85:4C:35:8F:C0:1F:D5:3A:F9:14:AE:2A:B6

Que es lo que me hace falta,

```
To get one, follow this link, follow the directions and press "Create" at the end:

https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_android_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE_ANDROID&r=D0:B7:C8:18:8F:1E:D4:85:4C:35:8F:C0:1F:D5:3A:F9:14:AE:2A:B6%3Bcom.example.basurapk

You can also add your credentials to an existing key, using these values:

Package name:
D0:B7:C8:18:8F:1E:D4:85:4C:35:8F:C0:1F:D5:3A:F9:14:AE:2A:B6

SHA-1 certificate fingerprint:
24:90:B4:1C:7F:FE:4D:7C:BA:D1:3D:2A:15:50:55:55:14:69:B9:12

Alternatively, follow the directions here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get-key

Once you have your key (it starts with "AIza"), replace the "google_maps_key"
string in this file.
-->
<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">
    <!-- key de google -->
</string>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Adrian :D, no muestres la key por acá, a menos que tenga las políticas de seguridad que indican que solo se puede utilizar desde una ip específica o un dominio.

Comment: Mirate el siguiente enlace: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/103765/google-maps-android-se-visualiza-en-blanco-en-release

Answer (score 0):

Es correcto lo que estas realizando, como se puede ver en la informaciòn de esta pregunta:

[Google Maps Android se visualiza en blanco en Release](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/103765/google-maps-android-se-visualiza-en-blanco-en-release)

registras el SHA-1 tanto de tu Keystore de desarrollo como el de producción.

Pero el problema puede deberse a dos causas:

- El paquete de la aplicación android que hace uso de mapas es incorrecto, debes revisar cual es el que se encuentra definido dentro del archivo `build.gradle` (veo por ahì que usaste com.example.basurapk).
- El paquete de la aplicaciòn no debe contener el caracter ",", como al parecer esta registrado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]