# Google Mpas se muestra completamente gris

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin.forms, xaml

Estoy desarrollando una app en Xamarin forms que requiere del api de google maps
esta app muestra completamente la pantalla del mapa pero no muestra el mapa, aparece completamente en blanco,

les muestro capturas de pantalla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
namespace utravel.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "utravel", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]

    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        const int RequestLocationId = 0;

        readonly string[] LocationPermissions =
        {
            Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation,
            Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation
        };

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
            CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            UserDialogs.Init(this);
            Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            if (requestCode == RequestLocationId)
            {
                if ((grantResults.Length == 1) && (grantResults[0] == (int)Permission.Granted)) ;
                // Permissions granted - display a message.

                else { }
                // Permissions denied - display a message.
            } 
            else
            {
                base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            }

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            base.OnStart();

            if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= 23)
            {
                if (CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation) != Permission.Granted)
                {
                    RequestPermissions(LocationPermissions, RequestLocationId);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Permissions already granted - display a message.
                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

y este es el manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.utravel" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <application android:label="utravel.Android">
      <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyAH-2B2k5I_zKrbJFHQVc3YCw******" />
      <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
      <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
      <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />

    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="true" />


</manifest>
```

y este seria el xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="utravel.Vistas.MapPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <maps:Map x:Name="map" />
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

el tema es que instale el codigo al pie de la letra segun microsoft y la cuenta del maps de google esta activa, envie el reclamo a google y aun no me responden

quisiera saber si existe la posibilidad de que sea un error en mi codigo o si existe algo en google maps que deba activar

Comment: Hola, lo ejecutas en android 9 o 10?

Comment: Tienes una id de google maps? necesitas una (en realidad dos, una para depuracion y otra si vas a publicar la app). Al menos en aplicaciones nativas, nunca he programado en xamarin. [Aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/maps-api) tienes los pasos explicados.

Comment: agrega tu clase mainactivity para verla.

Comment: Necesitas la API de google, y activarla desde la web

Answer (score 0):

Si revisas en la consola encontrarás un mensaje "contacting google map server"

si estas realizando pruebas desde crear una API Key y definirla en :

```
    ...
    ...
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="TU API KEY" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <!-- Necessary for apps that target Android 9.0 or higher -->
        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**El problema es que seguramente tu API KEY no es correcta o no esta habilitada**, recuerda que cuando realizas pruebas el Keystore que se esta usando es de debug pero cuando subes tu aplicación a la tienda se firma la app con un Keystore de producción (Release) por lo tanto debes habilitar ambas API KEY ya que ambas usan diferente `SHA-1`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[Obtención de una clave de la API de Google Maps](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/obtaining-a-google-maps-api-key?tabs=windows)

---

Este problema es similar en Android usando Google Maps:

[Google Maps Android se visualiza en gris (o blanco) en Release](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/103765/google-maps-android-se-visualiza-en-blanco-en-release)