# Visualizar Google Maps en Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin

Intento mandar a llamar Google Maps desde la Api de Xamarin, pero cuando ejecuto mi aplicación se queda en blanco sin mostrarme el mapa (sólo el logotipo de Google abajo)
Así mando a llamar mi mapa:

```
 public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap map)
    {
        GMap = map;
        //this.GMap = googleMap;

        LatLng latlng = new LatLng(40.776408, -73.970755); //New York
        LatLng latlong = GetCurrentLocation();

        CameraUpdate camera = CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngZoom(latlong, 10);
        GMap.MoveCamera(camera);

        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
        .SetPosition(GetCurrentLocation())
        .SetTitle("New York")
        .SetSnippet("AKA: The Big Apple")
        .Draggable(true);

        GMap.AddMarker(options);

        //GMap.MarkerClick += MMap_MarkerClick;
        //GMap.MarkerDragEnd += MMap_MarkerDragEnd;
    }
```

Alguna idea de qué podría fallarme? Uso una Api Key generada del sitio oficial

**UPDATE**

Generé ya el SHA-1 pero ahora no ejecuta la aplicación, la abre pero se cierra

Comment: Tuve el mismo error, la solución es registrar correctamente la aplicación en los servicios de google (https://console.developers.google.com), para mayor información seguir el siguiente link en donde sale explicado paso por paso como realizarlo (http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/google-maps-integration-in-xamarin-forms/)

Comment: @Erik trata de realizar el registro de tu API pero con el  SHA-1 Keystore del cual generarías tu aplicación. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/103765/google-maps-android-se-visualiza-en-blanco-en-release/103777#103777

Comment: Gracias @Jorgesys ya intenté generarla, pero me marca un error, debo colocarlo en otra pregunta o puedo ponerlo aquí??

Comment: Hola @EriK aquí puedes agregar las actualizaciones de información!

Comment: Ya logré obtener el SHA-1, pero sigue sin mostrarme el mapa

Comment: @EriK ah hehe! Primero, si ya obtuviste el  SHA-1 obten la  API KEY  ve a 
 https://console.developers.google.com , revisa esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6732/maps-android-studio-no-se-muestra , en cuanto a que se cierra que error marca el LogCat?

Comment: El LogCat no marca ningún error, marca que la aplicación se está ejecutando, se ejecuta la aplicación y luego se cierra.

Ya había generado mi API KEY pero sucede lo mismo

Comment: fijate que seguramente has generado tu clave SHA-1 de otra ubicacion... cuando compilas la apk, fijate de donde saca el keystore y genera la clave desde ese fichero y te va a funcionar.