# Error AndroidStudio implementando GoogleMaps

Tags: android-studio, google-maps, android-fragment

Buenos días y gracias de antemano, estoy implementando google maps en una aplicación y me aparece el siguiente petardazo : InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment , llevo un día entero dándole vueltas y no doy con la solución.

```
12-19 11:15:42.702 10823-10823/start2develop.mplaces E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: start2develop.mplaces, PID: 10823
                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{start2develop.mplaces/start2develop.mplaces.Mapa}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2444)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2504)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:165)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5546)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684)
                                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:558)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:434)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:420)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2219)
                                                                       at start2develop.mplaces.Mapa.onCreate(Mapa.java:35)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6367)
                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2397)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2504) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:165) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5546) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684) 
                                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:801)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:723)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:854)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:817)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:434) 
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:420) 
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2219) 
                                                                       at start2develop.mplaces.Mapa.onCreate(Mapa.java:35) 
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6367) 
                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2397) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2504) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:165) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5546) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684) 
                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
                                                                       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.q.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11951446:40)
                                                                       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.auth.e.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11951446:11)
                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11951446:112)
                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapFragmentDelegate(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11951446:25)
                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.h.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11951446:32)
                                                                       at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
                                                                       at bvd.a(:com.google.android.gms@11951446:2)
                                                                       at xdi.newMapFragmentDelegate(:com.google.android.gms@11951446:1)
                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapFragmentDelegate(:com.google.android.gms@11951446:2)
                                                                       at xdh.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@11951446:12)
                                                                       at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzed.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzf.zzH(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zzwg(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onInflate(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.onInflate(Fragment.java:1225)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3511)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActi
```

Mi código es el siguiente : actividad Mapa.java

```
    package start2develop.mplaces;

 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
 import android.graphics.Bitmap;
 import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable; 
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
 import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


 public class Mapa extends FragmentActivity
    implements OnMapReadyCallback, OnInfoWindowClickListener {
 private GoogleMap mapa;

@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mapa);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapa);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mapa = googleMap;
    mapa.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        mapa.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mapa.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mapa.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    }
    if (Lugares.size() > 0) {
        GeoPunto p = Lugares.elemento(0).getPosicion();
        mapa.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                new LatLng(p.getLatitud(), p.getLongitud()), 12));
    }
    for (int n=0; n<Lugares.size(); n++) {
        Lugar lugar = Lugares.elemento(n);
        GeoPunto p = lugar.getPosicion();
        if (p != null && p.getLatitud() != 0) {
            BitmapDrawable iconoDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) getResources()
                    .getDrawable(lugar.getTipo().getRecurso());
            Bitmap iGrande = iconoDrawable.getBitmap();
            Bitmap icono = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(iGrande,
                    iGrande.getWidth() / 7, iGrande.getHeight() / 7, false);
            mapa.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(p.getLatitud(), p.getLongitud()))
                    .title(lugar.getNombre()).snippet(lugar.getDireccion())
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icono)));
        }
    }
    mapa.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
}

@Override public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
    for (int id=0; id<Lugares.size(); id++){
        if (Lugares.elemento(id). getNombre()
                .equals(marker.getTitle())){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, VistaLugar.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", (long)id);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        } }}}
```

Mapa.xml ============================================================

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>




<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<fragment android:id="@+id/mapa"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml ====================================================

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
<permission
    android:name="start2develop.mplaces.permission.MAP_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>



<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="start2develop.mplaces.Principal">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Acercade"
        android:label="Acerca de..."
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"/>
    <activity android:name=".VistaLugar"
        android:label="MisLugares..."/>
    <activity android:name=".EdicionLugar"
        android:label="Editar lugar"/>
    <activity android:name=".Mapa"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

values /google_maps_api.xml============================

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
    <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve"
     translatable="false">
        AIzaSyBipkse1lv3Ok6KjLxLSi83AppkAU89oMs</string>
 </resources>
```

Comment: Hola @Raul.Rt Debes definir tu API KEY dentro del tag `<application>` de tu `AndroidManifest.xml`, al parecer lo tienes definido afuera de  `<application>`, si tienes habilitada la API KEY correctamente,entonces esto solucionará tu problema, saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es debido a que no puede inflar un layout, que en realidad es `mapa.xml`, pero en realidad este layout no se puede inflar debido a este problema:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that
>    is in the  element of
>   AndroidManifest.xml

Al tratar de cargar el `SupportMapFragment`, este no puede ser configurado correctamente:

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/mapa"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

**Debes definir tu API KEY dentro del tag `<application>` de tu `AndroidManifest.xml`, de hecho esto es el problema que es definido en el LogCat**, ya que tu lo estas realizando fuera de `<application>`:

```
 <application
        ...
        ...
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

 </application>
```

es importante habilitar esta API KEY, para que se visualice el mapa, asegura que esto sea realizado, ve a https://console.developers.google.com

[Maps Android Studio no se muestra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6732/maps-android-studio-no-se-muestra/6755#6755)

No olvides el permiso y la definición del feature:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
```

Comment: Efectivamente Jorgesys , estaba fuera de application , ya funciona correctamente , que rabia fallar en cosas así, pero bueno de todo se aprende, muchísimas gracias!

Comment: @Raul.Rt todos tenemos el mismo problema, un poco de experiencia y ya no nos sucede después, un placer ayudarte saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Yo tenía el mismo error, intenté colocando:

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

en mi manifest y funcionó, espero te sirva

Answer (score -1):

Según el código que has pegado, creo que te falta cerrar en el fichero xml con

```
</string>
</resources>
```

---

De todas formas para usar la KEY de google debería de ir en el fichero **google_maps_api.xml** y este fichero deberia de tener unicamente:

```
<resources>
<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve"
    translatable="false">
  AIzaSyBipkse1lv3Ok6KjLxLSi83AppkAU89oMs</string>
</resources>
```

Y el fichero **strings.xml**, debería de tener solo las cadenas a usar por la app:

```
<resources>
    <string nstrings.xmlame="app_name">MPlaces</string>
    <string name="title_activity_maps">otro texto para mis Mapas</string>
     .....
</resources>
```

Comment: Cierto, me comí el cierre al pegarlo aquí, he puesto la key en google_maps_api.xml pero sigue dándome el mismo error.