# No se importan librerías de Google Maps en Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps, android-fragment

Me estoy partiendo la cabeza con esto, no he podido mostrar el mapa de Google en un fragment, aparece todo gris, sólamente la palabra google en la esquina inferior izquierda.

Luego me doy cuenta de que en la clase del Fragment no importó las librerías y no se cómo hacerlo.

Aquí está la clase del Fragment del mapa:

```
package com.prestolunch.prestolunch.Fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.prestolunch.prestolunch.R;

public class mapaFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private View view;
private GoogleMap map;
private MapView mapView;
public mapaFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mapa, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mapView= (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mpa);
    if (mapView != null){
        mapView.onCreate(null);
        mapView.onResume();
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);

    }

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map=googleMap;
    LatLng place = new LatLng(26.932112, -105.645264);
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(place).title("Itp"));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(place));
}
}
```

Layout del fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragments.mapaFragment">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mpa"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Ayuda!

Comment: checa esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6732/maps-android-studio-no-se-muestra. Son varias cosas atener en cuenta: obtener la key, agregar dependencias en el gradle, cambios en el manifest

Comment: has agregado tu API KEY?

Comment: Si la tengo! No se cual sea el problema, porque cuando creo un nuevo proyecto iniciando directamente con el layout de Google Maps no hay ningún error